# Cardinality of a set of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question is basically to find the number of elements in the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^{60} = -1 , z^k \neq -1, 0<k<60 \}$.

As is quite obvious with the kind of question,I am a self-studying novice, but the only idea I could get was to just use $\theta = \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{60}$, which makes it a routine $n$-th root problem. But I am not sure how the condition on $k$ comes into this? A hint would suffice or a link if this is a duplicate(or close to being one).

Comment: Which part of India are you from?

Comment: I am from the northern part of coastal Karnataka, South India. Any particular reason for asking?

Comment: Yes. I used to live in Bangalore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that all solutions of the equation $z^{60} = -1$ are of the form

$$z_n=e^{\frac{(2n + 1)\pi}{60}i}$$

There are $60$ values of $z$ here, but there is another condition you must fulfill! The value $z^k$ must *not* be equal to $-1$ for *any* other value $k<60$. If you take $n=1$ in your case, then

$z_1 = e^{\frac{3\pi}{60}i} = e^{\frac{\pi}{20}i}$, meaning that $z_1^{20} = e^{\pi i} = -1$. That means that $z_1$ is **not** in your set! There may be other candidates that are not in the set, and this is the part of the question you still need to explore.

Comment: yeah..thats true...but is there any way to do this without explicitly looking for these elements....one can eliminate n values of 0,1, 2, 7. I mean odd values which end up as factors of 60...everything else should be fine right?

Comment: Oh..the above comment is off the tune. I just looked at integer values. Can you shed a bit more light on this?Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why would you eliminate the value $n=0$?

Comment: @Vishesh I advise you to look at what goes wrong with $n=1$... Think about divisibility.

Comment: Ok....yeah thats what I meant in my first comment about weeding out the factors..and taking only those values which end up being relatively prime to 60.I got it anyway, thanks...There seem to be a multitude of answers propping up, but since yours was the first and doesn't spoil much, I will accept it.

Comment: Relatively prime to $60$ is precisely the property you needed to figure out. Job done :)

Answer (score 2):

Taking modulus both sides: $|z|^{60} = |-1| = 1 \Rightarrow |z| = 1$ since $|z| \geq 0$. Thus $z = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, and using De Moivre's theorem: $z^{60} = \cos (60\theta) + i\sin(60\theta) = -1 \to \cos (60\theta) = -1, \sin (60\theta) = 0 \to 60\theta = (2n+1)\pi \to \theta = \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{60}$. You want those $n$ such that $\text{gcd}(2n+1,60) = 1$. Can you count them out?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$z=r\cos\theta + ir\sin\theta$$

Then

$$z^{60}=r^{60}\cos60\theta + ir^{60}\sin60\theta$$

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

The set you find is a superset $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z^{60} = -1\}$. You have to exclude those numbers which raised a smaller power than $60$ equals $-1$, i.e. $z^p = -1$ for some $p < 60$. But note that for such $z$ we have
$$-1 = z^{60} = (z^p)^{\frac{60}{p}} = (-1)^{\frac{60}{p}} \implies (-1)^{1-\frac{60}{p}} = 1$$
and therefore $1-\frac{60}{p} \neq 0$ is even and finally $\frac{60}{p} \neq 1$ is odd. This is only possible when $p$ is a factor of $60$. Of all factors of $60$, $\frac{60}{p} \neq 1$ is odd if and only if $p \in \{4,12,20\}$ if and only if $n \in \{1,2,7\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a typical $n$-th root problem. The set of all 60th roots of $-1$ is the set
$$\left\{\text{exp}\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi i}{60}\right) : n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 59\right\} = \text{exp}\left(\left\{\frac{\pi i}{60},\frac{\pi i}{20},\frac{\pi i}{12},\frac{7\pi i}{60}, \frac{3 \pi i}{20}, \cdots \right\}\right).$$
We need to find the subset of these numbers that aren't the $k$-th roots of $-1$ for any $k = 1, 2, \ldots 59$. But the 20th power of the second number is $-1$, and the 12th power of the third is $-1$, but for any power we put exp$\left(\frac{7 \pi i}{60} \right)$ to any power less than 60, we will not get $-1$ (why?). This limits us to only a few roots, namely those whose denominators in the exponent is not 60.

Comment: Thanks....yeah it is quite routine...my complex analysis skills are really bad thats all.